# VAST ADs not playing in video player on website

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the link to the site

(Music Videos(Player))
http://bluntrollers.co/Live%20Stream.html

I have tried several different options, if you have a better one, please list it if you
Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I can't fix it on my own I will have to spend $15 on Fiverr to get a video player. Thanks for all your help!

Here's is my code:

````
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/videojs_5.vast.vpaid.min.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
<CENTER>Music Videos</CENTER>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.20.5/video.js'></script>
    <video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
    poster="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png"
    data-setup='{
      "plugins": {
      "vastClient": {
        "adTagUrl": "https://www.movcpm.com/watch.xml?key=9ccb16032b77eabffbe9fbf2194c0464",
        "adCancelTimeout": 5000,
        "adsEnabled": true
        }
      }
    }'>
  <source src="/VidUploads/Natural%20-%20The%20Future%20%28Prod.%20by%20MURDA%20TAPE%29.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
  <p class="vjs-no-js">
    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
    <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
  </p>
</video>
</CENTER>
</P>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.6/video.js"></script>
</body>```
````

Comment: We need more info to help. Let's start with the error your getting...

Comment: it says videojs is not a function..and vastClient could not be found.

Comment: `<script src="/path/to/videojs_5.vast.vpaid.min.js"></script>` isn't updated to an actual path it looks like.

Comment: I have uploaded the required documents to my server and change the path to <script src="/videojsfiles/videojs_5.vast.vpaid.min.js"></script>

Comment: Turns out you were right, I needed to upload the required documents it was missing and update the file path. My ads are now working!! I am so thankful. Whew! Now if I can just figure out how to implement a playlist and live streaming?? hmm...

Comment: Good deal, I'll post as an answer for you to accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line needs the path to load the js.

```
<script src="/path/to/videojs_5.vast.vpaid.min.js"></script>
```